# A validator with wrong result

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am using JSF2.0/primefaces

I want to create a validator, the validator should validate the format of an Input text (the Input has the type Integer).The problem is that the validator always displays `Not valid`.

This is the validator:

```
public void validateInputHours(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
    Object value) throws ValidatorException {
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-24]");
Matcher m = p.matcher((String) value);
if (!m.matches())
    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(
            FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Not valid",
            "Not valid"));
}
```

The input Text:

```
<p:inputText  validator="#{Control.validateInputHours}" style="width: 18px"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state:

> the validator should validate the format of an Input text (the Input has the type Integer)

and then your validator performs:

`Matcher m = p.matcher((String) value);`

which should result in a `ClassCastException` being thrown if you attempt to cast an Integer to a String. I suspect you are "eating" the ClassCastException somewhere, and you are issuing a generic message with value `Not valid`.

The following snippets, for instance, work (against Primefaces 3.0M2):

---

The Facelet:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText value="#{control.value}"  validator="#{control.validateInputHours}" style="width: 18px"/>
    <h:commandButton action="#{control.process}" />
    <h:messages globalOnly="true" />
</h:form>
```

---

The Managed Bean:

```
private int value;

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

...
public void validateInputHours(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    Integer hours = (Integer) value; // the value will be the value from the model after the Apply-Request-Values phase is complete
    if (hours < 0 || hours > 24) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Not valid",
                "Not valid"));
    }
}
```

---

If you want to check the format of the `value` against a regex, then it's representation in the model should be a `String`, and not an `Integer`/`int`. There again, Jon Skeet's answer is valid. `[0-24]` will not do what you think it is doing.

Comment: as you have said I had state  "the validator should validate the format of an Input text (the Input has the type Integer)" because I have waited an exception but no exception was thrown !

Comment: @rym, I don't understand. I think you should post the code of the model, atleast for the attribute being validated. I converted my example to use a `String` instead of an `int` and it threw a `ClassCastException` on invoking the validator. This was conveyed because my `faces-config.xml` contain the config parameters to run JSF in a Development mode. I think you are not running in Development mode or that you are doing something else that is masking the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression will only match a single digit, '0', '1', '2' or '4'. I suspect that's not what you intended.

I suspect you want something like:

```
[0-9]|([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])
```

So that will match a single digit 0-9, or 00-19, or 20-23. (It's not allowing 24 at the moment - change the final "3" to a "4" if you really want to include 24 as a valid value.)

That's assuming my regex is right - it'll be *something* like that. That's if you really want to use a regex - an alternative would be to try to parse the value as an integer, and then check that it's in the right range.

Finally, I would expect there to be open source libraries that handle this kind of thing for you in a very simple way - it's worth checking you're not reinventing the wheel...